# Error When Trying To Fetch Webhooks List via Shopify API

Tags: php, api, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am building a Shopify App in PHP using Shopify's own [PHP library for Shopify API](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php)

When I try to fetch current webhooks, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession() must be of the type array, null given, called in /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/index.php on line 45 and defined in /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php:158 Stack trace: #0 /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/index.php(45): Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession(NULL, NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php on line 158

PHP code:

```
$this->test_session = Utils::loadCurrentSession(
    $requestHeaders,
    $requestCookies,
    $isOnline
);
Webhookv2::webhooks(
    $this->test_session, // Session
    [], // Url Ids
    [], // Params
);
```

[Utils.php](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php/blob/main/src/Utils.php) is part of the Shopify API PHP library

Comment: It seems the three variables you're passing (`$requestHeaders`, `$requestCookies` and , `$isOnline `) are all null, make sure they are the types they need to be.

Comment: @SamiAkkawi Yes but why are null variables being supplied by [Utils.php](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php/blob/main/src/Utils.php), which is part of Shopify API's official PHP library.

Comment: `$requestHeaders`, `$requestCookies` and `$isOnline` are not being supplied by `Utils`, these are from your script, you need to supply these to `Utils` for it to do its thing.

Comment: @SamiAkkawi Oh okay, let me do that and update back here.